# Execute function from unknow type T

Tags: c#, function

I have a class like this:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    //Other stuff...

    public static static int TestFunction(int c, int d)
    {
         //Other stuff...
         return c + d;
    }
}
```

and I have many differend classes like this with differend properties but always with a "TestFunction" function with differend content (like +/*/:/-).

Now I want to to build another function that calls this function without knowing the type of the function but I know that "Testfunction" is always there.

Here is my try:

```
public static int AnotherFunction<T>(T inClass, int c, int d)
{
    //Other stuff...
    return inClass.TestFunction(c, d);
}
```

The functions are for showing purposes simplyfied (dont just say "call the function directly because it doesnt do much").
The Problem is that Visual Studio says "TestFunction" is unknown.
How can I do this without knowing what class I get?

Comment: You can't, because it's static. Why is it static? Or well you could, using reflection, but you don't want to. If it weren't, you could use an interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an interface and the types can inherit from it and provide their own implementation for those.

Then you can constraint your method for the generic parameter on that interface type so that all types inheriting from it can call respective implementation.

See the following :

```
public interface IInterface
{
   int TestFunction(int c, int d);
}

public class TestClass : IInterface
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    //Other stuff...

    public int TestFunction(int c, int d)
    {
         //Other stuff...
         return c + d;
    }
}
```

and now you can write a method like:

```
public static int AnotherFunction<T>(T inClass, int c, int d) where T : IInterface
{
   //Other stuff...
   return inClass.TestFunction(c, d);
}
```

Hope it gives you idea.